# Positional Rankings and Dealing with Ties in Python

Tags: python, django, math

*(I apologize that previous versions of this question displayed the wrong function that I need to fix, this has been remedied and I hope the question makes a little more sense now.)*

I have a list of objects with scores, and I'm attempting to assign rank to them based on those scores. Below is basically how I output my data.

```
sorted_scores = [
    ('Apolo Ohno', 0),
    ('Shanie Davis', -1),
    ('Bodie Miller', -2),
    ('Lindsay Vohn', -3),  
    ('Shawn White', -3),
    ('Bryan Veloso', -4)
]
```

I have a tie. Now, the function that assigns positions to the objects above right now is a simple for loop that just assigns the value of `i` as the object's final position.

```
positions = {}

i = 1
for key, value in sorted_list:
    # Since in my codebase the strings are IDs, I use the key to fetch the object.
    if value is not None:
        positions[key] = i
        i += 1
```

So that'll obviously return:

```
positions = {
    'Apolo Ohno': 1,
    'Shanie Davis': 2,
    'Bodie Miller': 3,
    'Lindsay Vohn': 4,        
    'Shawn White': 5,
    'Bryan Veloso': 6
}
```

Hopefully that makes some sense. The meat of the question is that loop. What makes more sense is if it returns them like so:

```
positions = {
    'Apolo Ohno': 1,
    'Shanie Davis': 2,
    'Bodie Miller': 3,
    'Lindsay Vohn': 4, # Same value.
    'Shawn White': 4, # Same value.
    'Bryan Veloso': 6
}
```

How would I edit the function above to do that, keeping in mind that I could have any number of ties at any given time depending on how many of my members ranked said object? The highest rank should be 1, so it can be displayed as such: `<rank>/<total # of people>`

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It always made sense, you just need to clean all the irrelevant cruft away. Keep going. The member ranking stuff is irrelevant to your question. Lose foo_ranking and bar ranking. Start with: "I have a list of tuples (object_id, score). Given ties can happen, how do I ...". Make it plain which of highest/lowest score means rank of 0 (or 1).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate learning how to ask a concise question, especially when it comes to topics like this. :)

Comment: Any particular reason why you accepted that answer in preference to an earlier equivalent answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> sorted_scores = [
...     ('Apolo Ohno', 0),
...     ('Shanie Davis', -1),
...     ('Bodie Miller', -2),
...     ('Lindsay Vohn', -3),  
...     ('Shawn White', -3),
...     ('Bryan Veloso',-4)
... ]
>>> 
>>> res = {}
>>> prev = None
>>> for i,(k,v) in enumerate(sorted_scores):
...     if v!=prev:
...         place,prev = i+1,v
...     res[k] = place
... 
>>> print res
{'Apolo Ohno': 1, 'Bryan Veloso': 6, 'Shanie Davis': 2, 'Lindsay Vohn': 4, 'Bodie Miller': 3, 'Shawn White': 4}
```

Remember that dicts are unordered, so to iterate in order of place, you need to do this

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> print sorted(res.items(),key=itemgetter(1))
[('Apolo Ohno', 1), ('Shanie Davis', 2), ('Bodie Miller', 3), ('Lindsay Vohn', 4), ('Shawn White', 4), ('Bryan Veloso', 6)]
```

Comment: much shorter than my solution.   Good call using enumerate.

Comment: @vishvananda: Please also do a critique on my (earlier) answer :-)

Comment: @John: Sorry john, I missed the fact that your answer uses the same technique.

Answer (score 3):

**=== Update after change/clarification of specs ===**

```
# coding: ascii

def ranks_from_scores(sorted_scores):
    """sorted_scores: a list of tuples (object_id, score), sorted by score DESCENDING
       return a mapping of object IDs to ranks
    """
    ranks = {}
    previous_score = object()
    for index, (obj_id, score) in enumerate(sorted_scores):
        if score != previous_score:
            previous_score = score
            rank = index + 1
        ranks[obj_id] = rank
    return ranks

from operator import itemgetter
import pprint

scores0 = dict([
    ('Apolo Ohno', 0),
    ('Shanie Davis', -1),
    ('Bodie Miller', -2),
    ('Lindsay Vohn', -3),
    ('Shawn White', -3)
    ])

scores1 = {
    'lorem': 100,
    'ipsum': 200,
    'dolor': 300,
    'sit': 300,
    'amet': 300,
    'quia': 400,
    'consectetur': 500,
    'adipiscing': 500,
    'elit': 600,
    }

scores2 = {
    'lorem': 100,
    'ipsum': 200,
    'dolor': 300,
    'sit': 300,
    'amet': 300,
    'quia': 400,
    'consectetur': 500,
    'adipiscing': 500,
    'elit': 6000,
    }

import pprint
funcs = (ranks_from_scores, ) # Watch this space!
tests = (scores0, scores1, scores2)

for test in tests:
    print
    test_list = sorted(test.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    print "Input:", test_list
    for func in funcs:
        result = func(test_list)
        print "%s ->" % func.__name__
        pprint.pprint(result)
```

Results:

```
Input: [('Apolo Ohno', 0), ('Shanie Davis', -1), ('Bodie Miller', -2), ('Lindsay
 Vohn', -3), ('Shawn White', -3)]
ranks_from_scores ->
{'Apolo Ohno': 1,
 'Bodie Miller': 3,
 'Lindsay Vohn': 4,
 'Shanie Davis': 2,
 'Shawn White': 4}

Input: [('elit', 600), ('consectetur', 500), ('adipiscing', 500), ('quia', 400),
 ('dolor', 300), ('sit', 300), ('amet', 300), ('ipsum', 200), ('lorem', 100)]
ranks_from_scores ->
{'adipiscing': 2,
 'amet': 5,
 'consectetur': 2,
 'dolor': 5,
 'elit': 1,
 'ipsum': 8,
 'lorem': 9,
 'quia': 4,
 'sit': 5}

Input: [('elit', 6000), ('consectetur', 500), ('adipiscing', 500), ('quia', 400)
, ('dolor', 300), ('sit', 300), ('amet', 300), ('ipsum', 200), ('lorem', 100)]
ranks_from_scores ->
{'adipiscing': 2,
 'amet': 5,
 'consectetur': 2,
 'dolor': 5,
 'elit': 1,
 'ipsum': 8,
 'lorem': 9,
 'quia': 4,
 'sit': 5}
```

**=== original submission ===**

This code assumes that you really want the highest score to get rank 1, not the lowest score getting rank 1 (or 0!).

```
# coding: ascii

def ranks_from_scores(scores, debug=False):
    """scores (a mapping of object IDs to scores)
       return a mapping of object IDs to ranks
    """
    alist = [(v, k) for k, v in scores.items()]
    alist.sort(reverse=True)
    if debug: print 'alist:', alist
    bdict = {}
    previous_score = object()
    for posn, (score, obj_id) in enumerate(alist):
        if score != previous_score:
            previous_score = score
            rank = posn + 1
        bdict[obj_id] = rank
    if debug:
        print 'bdict:', bdict
        blist = [(v, k) for k, v in bdict.items()]
        print 'blist:', sorted(blist)
    return bdict

ranks_from_scores(
    {'q': 10, 'w': 20, 'e': 20, 'r': 20, 't': 30},
    debug=True,
    )
```

Output:

```
alist: [(30, 't'), (20, 'w'), (20, 'r'), (20, 'e'), (10, 'q')]
bdict: {'q': 5, 'r': 2, 'e': 2, 't': 1, 'w': 2}
blist: [(1, 't'), (2, 'e'), (2, 'r'), (2, 'w'), (5, 'q')]
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is not to calculate the element's position is some arbitrary sequence, but rather to calculate how many other elements have a better score.

**EDIT:**

By popular demand, O(n)'ed and everything:

```
positions = {}
cur_score = None # Score we're examining
cur_count = 0 # Number of others that we've seen with this score

for ix, (name, score) in enumerate(sorted_scores):
  if score == cur_score: # Same score for this player as previous
    cur_count += 1
  else: # Different score from before
    cur_score = score
    cur_count = 0
  positions[name] = ix - cur_count + 1 # Add 1 because ix is 0-based

print positions
```

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down, as this suggestion is extremely reasonable and correct.  It's an invariant that every rank value in a list of "ranks with ties" is exactly the number of better scores (+1, usually).  Depending on the strategy for solving the problem, Ignacio's suggestion has extra value as it is perfectly parallelizable and--as such--wonderfully suited to multi-threaded/multi-process solutions.

Comment: Well it wasn't me ... but the reasons may well have included "no code".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use the `sorted` and `enumerate` builtins, the `groupby` method from `itertools` and the `itemgetter` method from `operator`. Assumes higher scores are better... (if lower scores are better, change `reverse=True` to `reverse=False`)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> scores = {
...     'lorem': 100,
...     'ipsum': 200,
...     'dolor': 300,
...     'sit': 300,
...     'amet': 300,
...     'quia': 400,
...     'consectetur': 500,
...     'adipiscing': 500,
...     'elit': 600,
...     }
>>> sorted_items = sorted(scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
>>> groups = groupby(sorted_items, itemgetter(1))
>>> for rank, (score, items) in enumerate(groups):
...     print rank+1, map(itemgetter(0), items)
... 
1 ['elit']
2 ['consectetur', 'adipiscing']
3 ['quia']
4 ['dolor', 'sit', 'amet']
5 ['ipsum']
6 ['lorem']
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to do what the OP wants: note his example of "more sensible" output `positions = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 2, '4': 2, '5': 5, '6': 6}` i.e. one gets first prize, three share second prize, the fifth is rank FIVE; you would have the fifth as rank THREE.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Here's one simple way to do it by modifying your code a little rather than importing modules:

```
prev = None
rank = 0
incr = 1
positions = {}
for key, value in sorted_list:
    if value is not None:
        if value != prev:
            rank += incr
            incr = 1
        else:
            incr += 1
        positions[key] = rank
        prev = value
```

**A Test**

For

```
sorted_list = [
    ('Apolo Ohno', 0),
    ('Shanie Davis', -1),
    ('Bodie Miller', -2),
    ('Lindsay Vohn', -3),  
    ('Shawn White', -3),
    ('Bryan Veloso',-4)
]
```

I get positions as:

```
{'Apolo Ohno': 1, 
'Shanie Davis': 2,
 'Bodie Miller': 3,
 'Lindsay Vohn': 4,
 'Shawn White': 4,
 'Bryan Veloso': 6}
```

which I think is what you are going for even though you aren't quite clear about whether there should be a 6 after the two 4's.

Comment: Indeed, there should be a 6. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of my answer.  I guess great minds think alike?

Comment: @vishvananda: It seems to be endemic :-(

Comment: @vishvananda Yours was incorrect when I posted mine, but then you edited yours.

Comment: I see.  I guess I missed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that combines aspects of a few of the other solutions into a flexible generator function.

```py
def rank_sorted(sequence, start=1, key=None, reverse=True):
    """A combination of `enumerate` and `sorted` iterators that deals
    with tied ranks.

    """
    previous_value = object()  # won't compare equal to anything
    sorted_iterator = sorted(sequence, key=key, reverse=reverse)
    for index, item in enumerate(sorted_iterator, start=start):

        # use key function to choose value if given
        if key is None:
            value = item
        else:
            value = key(item)

        # only update rank when sort value changes
        if value != previous_value:
            previous_value = value
            rank = index

        yield rank, item
```

You can call with different values for `start`, `key`, and `reverse` to allow for ranks to start at 0 or 1, to pass a custom key function (like `itemgetter(1)` for sorting dictionaries by value), and to easily switch to having lower scores considered higher ranking. Using the example in the original question:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

sorted_scores = [
    ('Apolo Ohno', 0),
    ('Shanie Davis', -1),
    ('Bodie Miller', -2),
    ('Lindsay Vohn', -3),  
    ('Shawn White', -3),
    ('Bryan Veloso', -4)
]

higher_is_better = dict(
    (name, rank)
    for rank, (name, score)
    in rank_sorted(sorted_scores, key=itemgetter(1))
)
# {'Apolo Ohno': 1, 'Bryan Veloso': 6, 'Shanie Davis': 2, 'Lindsay Vohn': 4, 'Bodie Miller': 3, 'Shawn White': 4}

lower_is_better = dict(
    (name, rank)
    for rank, (name, score)
    in rank_sorted(sorted_scores, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=False)
)
# {'Apolo Ohno': 6, 'Bryan Veloso': 1, 'Shanie Davis': 5, 'Lindsay Vohn': 2, 'Bodie Miller': 4, 'Shawn White': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as the best answer, just keeping the ordinals instead of skiping to the next position at the ranking:
i.e.: ranking = [1,2,3,4,4,5] instead of ranking = [1,2,3,4,4,6]

```
    sorted_scores = [
     ('Apolo Ohno', 0),
     ('Shanie Davis', -1),
     ('Bodie Miller', -2),
     ('Lindsay Vohn', -3),  
     ('Shawn White', -3),
     ('Bryan Veloso',-4)
]

res = {}
prev = None
n = 0 
for k,v in sorted_scores:
    if v!=prev:
        n +=1 
        place,prev = n,v
    res[k] = place

print (res)
{'Apolo Ohno': 1, 'Shanie Davis': 2, 'Bodie Miller': 3, 'Lindsay Vohn': 4, 'Shawn White': 4, 'Bryan Veloso': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having to make a bunch of assumptions about what it is you want to do, but here's an attempt:

```python
scores = {
    'lorem': 100,
    'ipsum': 200,
    'dolor': 300,
    'sit': 300,
    'amet': 300,
    'quia': 400,
    'consectetur': 500,
    'adipiscing': 500,
    'elit': 600,
}

groups = {}
for (member, score) in scores.items():
    if score not in groups:
        groups[score] = [member]
    else:
        groups[score].append(member)

positions = {}
for (rank, (score, members)) in enumerate(groups.items()):
    for member in members:
        positions[member] = rank
```

Expanded for detail, to show the working:

```python
>>> import pprint
>>> scores = {
...     'lorem': 100,
...     'ipsum': 200,
...     'dolor': 300,
...     'sit': 300,
...     'amet': 300,
...     'quia': 400,
...     'consectetur': 500,
...     'adipiscing': 500,
...     'elit': 600,
... }
>>> groups = {}
>>> for (member, score) in scores.items():
...     if score not in groups:
...         groups[score] = [member]
...     else:
...         groups[score].append(member)
...
>>> pprint.pprint(groups)
{100: ['lorem'],
 200: ['ipsum'],
 300: ['sit', 'dolor', 'amet'],
 400: ['quia'],
 500: ['consectetur', 'adipiscing'],
 600: ['elit']}
>>> positions = {}
>>> for (rank, (score, members)) in enumerate(groups.items()):
...     for member in members:
...         positions[member] = rank
...
>>> pprint.pprint(positions)
{'adipiscing': 4,
 'amet': 2,
 'consectetur': 4,
 'dolor': 2,
 'elit': 5,
 'ipsum': 1,
 'lorem': 0,
 'quia': 3,
 'sit': 2}
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted(positions.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]))
[('lorem', 0),
 ('ipsum', 1),
 ('sit', 2),
 ('dolor', 2),
 ('amet', 2),
 ('quia', 3),
 ('consectetur', 4),
 ('adipiscing', 4),
 ('elit', 5)]
```

Comment: You import `itertools` but never use it. Try putting stand-alone code in a file and running it from the command line.

Comment: Much worse: It doesn't work. Your single correct result is an accident. Change the score of elit from 600 to 6000 (still running last on the low-score-is-better regime) and see what happens. You are assuming incorrectly that groups.items() is sorted on score.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it

```
last = None
position = 0
delta = 1
for key, value in sorted_list:
    if value is not None:
        if value != last:
            position += delta
            delta = 1
        else:
            delta += 1
        # i believe this is supposed to be [key] not [value] in OP's code
        positions[key] = position
        last = value
```

Comment: If there is a two way tie for 4th place, I think the next place should be 6th

Comment: @gnibbler: What you say has a serendipitous combination of two attributes (a) it's sensible (b) it's what the OP expressly wants.

Comment: @gnibbler: Good point.  I fixed the code according to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sorted_scores = [
...     ('Apolo Ohno', 0),
...     ('Shanie Davis', -1),
...     ('Bodie Miller', -2),
...     ('Lindsay Vohn', -3),  
...     ('Shawn White', -3),
...     ('Bryan Veloso',-4)
... ]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> 
>>> place=1
>>> res={}
>>> for _,items in groupby(sorted_scores,key=itemgetter(1)):
...     for i,item in enumerate(items):
...         res[item[0]]= place
...     place+=i+1
... 
>>> print res
{'Apolo Ohno': 1, 'Bryan Veloso': 6, 'Shanie Davis': 2, 'Lindsay Vohn': 4, 'Bodie Miller': 3, 'Shawn White': 4}
```

Remember that dicts are unordered, so to iterate in order of place, you need to do this

```
>>> print sorted(res.items(),key=itemgetter(1))
[('Apolo Ohno', 1), ('Shanie Davis', 2), ('Bodie Miller', 3), ('Lindsay Vohn', 4), ('Shawn White', 4), ('Bryan Veloso', 6)]
```